# About affine map on three dimensional euclidean space

Tags: affine-geometry

An affine map $(t,M)$ with $t\in R^3$ and matrix $M$ maps $x\in R^3$ into $t+Mx$. It has property $P$ if for any $x$ with $|x|\leq 1$ then $|t+Mx|\leq 1$.

Our goal is to characterize the set of such maps with property $P$, that is characterized the set of $(t,M)$.

My question here is to give polynomial constraint of the above property $P$ if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Polar Decomposition on M, M=UJ, where U is unity and J is positive. 
Suppose t=U s.

Then |t+Mx| =|s+Jx|=~)

U can do this:)